# Spring Security with oAuth2 CORS issue on spring boot

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot. I have implemented Spring Security with oAuth2 and get acesstoken successfully from spring Security. But when I try to request with token with "Authorization" header..

```
config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer 0d634d2b-3900-4ca4-a462-cf729e8d0c72';
```

and my `CORS` filter is as :

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RequestFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT,DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            if (request.getMethod()!="OPTIONS") {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            } else {
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

But still it given CORS issue.

Please help me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solve. I have send token as wrong way

```
config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer 0d634d2b-3900-4ca4-a462-cf729e8d0c72';
```

right way is:

```
config.headers.authorization = 'Bearer 0d634d2b-3900-4ca4-a462-cf729e8d0c72';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your Access-Control-Allow-Headers like this:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Authorization, Content-Type");
```

Comment: same response "Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match '*". Now if am change his value to 'request.getHeader("Origin")' then "expected 'true' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'"